# What's the difference between software engineering and software project?

Tags: terminology

I find that I'm confused between the terms "software engineering" and "software project".

What is the difference between these? I suspect that "software engineering" may focus on a different aspect, but I'm not 100% sure. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Hi Lovespring, I edited this a bit to try and make it fit our Q&A format a bit better. If there's more you can add to more clearly describe your problem, please feel free to [edit]. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Study of different approaches like design, development, operation, and maintenance of software and applicaiton of these concepts can be termed as software engineering.
A project involving Software which has fixed goal and limited resources to complete can be termed as software project.

I tend to think that to execute a software project you need to implement software engineering concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add in the software project fixed goal, limited resources and limited time to complete the project.  To complete the software project you use software engineering practices like design, development, testing, deploy and operation  & maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

A software project is a limited time effort to produce discrete piece of software. Software projects end. Software engineering does not end.